# How do I make child print the signal that killed it?

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork, posix

I have the following code where parent is creating multiple child processes and killing them afterwards. Once killed, I want to print what killed the child (signal in this case). However, the code isnt printing that. what seems to be the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int i;

static void signal_handler(int signo)
{
  if (signo == SIGUSR1)
  {
    printf("child %d received sigusr1\n", i + 1);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  char buff[50];
  int status;

  if (signal(SIGUSR1, signal_handler) == SIGUSR1)
  {
    perror("Signal handling error");
  }

  pid_t cpid, count;

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    cpid = fork();

    if (cpid == 0)
    {
      sleep(10);

      //exit(0);
    }
    else if (cpid > 0)
    {
      kill(cpid, SIGUSR1);
      int status;
      int n = waitpid(cpid, &status, 0);

      if (n != cpid)
      {
        perror("error");
      }

      if (WIFSIGNALED(status))
      { /* get WTERMSIG(status)    */
        printf("killed by signal=%d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
      }
    }
    else
    {
      perror("Fork error: ");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well - I guess the children are terminated with exit(0) before the kill signal from the parent arrives. Should keep the children alive e.g. with sleep() so they are still around for the SIGUSR signal to arrive.

Comment: I tried that but its still not printing this part:
        printf("killed by signal=%d\n");
                    WTERMSIG(status);

Answer (score 1):

> WIFSIGNALED(stat_val) - Evaluates to a non-zero value if status was returned for a child process that terminated due to the  receipt of **a signal that was not caught**

Your signals are being caught (when they are received before they exit).

You have other problems that others have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`waitpid`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) instead, and be sure to handle *both* normal exit and killed-by-signal:

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if (pid == 0)
{
    exit(0);
}
else if (pid > 0)
{
    int status;
    int n = waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

    if (n != pid)                 { /* error */ }
    else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) { /* get WTERMSIG(status)    */ }
    else if (WIFEXITED(status))   { /* get WEXITSTATUS(status) */ }
}
else if (pid < 0)
{
    /* error */
}
```

As you can see from the documentation, `wait` will wait for *any* child, not just the current one. And of course its entirely possible that the child exits normally before receiving the signal.

You can stop the child from exiting normally by calling [`pause`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html), but the signal will only kill the child if it *doesn't* get handled. If the signal handler returns, `pause` returns, too.

Comment: how do I make sure that the child is killed by signal only?

Comment: @user3015353: Make the child not exit, e.g. sleep indefinitely.

Comment: @user3015353: Or call `pause` in the child.

Comment: I am making it sleep for a longer period of time but it is still not working i.e it is still not printing 'killed by signal..' line

Comment: As proposed by @duck, I removed the signal handler, and now the 'killed by signal line' is getting printed. Thank you  for your help.

Comment: @user3015353: if you handle the signal, it doesn't kill you!

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit. What happens when I handle it then?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the actual code of your app?

```
printf("killed by signal=%d\n");
WTERMSIG(status);
```

If so, the second line has no effect, try changing it to:

```
printf("killed by signal=%d\n", WTERMSIG(status));
```

Comment: I have posted the edited version can you please see it. The line 'killed by signal' is still not getting printed

Comment: As proposed by @duck, I removed the signal handler, and now the 'killed by signal line' is getting printed. Thankyou  for your help.